# Multiply a row vector with a matrix of corresponding columns based on IDs

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R and I have managed to write a code which has led me to two matrices. Matrix A looks like this:

```
   ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
row1 1   3   2   2       
row2 2   1   3   1          
row3 3   2   1   2          
row4 2   1   2   3
```

And matrix B looks like

```
   ID1 ID2 ID3 ID3.1 ID4 
row1 1.11 1.23 0.94 0.95
```

As you can see there is one extra column in Matrix B. Firstly I would need to match the two matrices by columnID so I can get rid of the extra column in matrix B.

I would like to multiply the two matrices and sum the products across each row. I basically Need help with matching with IDs in matrix A and B please.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for allowing me to join the StackOverflowcommunity. I have edited my question. Hope its clearer now. Thanks

Comment: @sajman Your edit has significantly changed the original question, or at least largely extended the scope. This is quite confusing also for other readers, since the answer that I posted below referred to the previous question, and now it no longer seems to correspond to what is currently asked in the post. Instead of moving the target, I recommend that you roll back to your original question and ask a new, separate one which addresses the new issues that you raised in the edited version of your post.

Comment: @RHertel Thank you for pointing that out. I will roll back to the original question which requested a method to simply multiply matrix a with matrix b after matching on ID's.

Comment: @sajman Thank you for following my suggestion. If you have further questions please don't hesitate to write a new post. A clear question with a well-defined problem statement, as well as a sufficiently precise definition of the input data and of the desired output usually receives very quickly a number of high-quality replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix `B` described in the OP is apparently wrong. It has four entries but five column names. Assuming a matrix `B`

```
> B
#      ID1  ID2  ID3 ID3.1  ID4
#row1 1.11 1.23 0.94  0.95 0.96
```

we can use, e.g.,

```
t(t(A) * B[colnames(B) %in% colnames(A)])
```

which yields

```
      ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4
row1 1.11 3.69 1.88 1.92
row2 2.22 1.23 2.82 0.96
row3 3.33 2.46 0.94 1.92
row4 2.22 1.23 1.88 2.88
```

If I understood the question correctly, this is the desired output.

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**

Following the most recent edit of the post, you want to perform a sum across each row. The function `rowSums()` is tailored for this:

```
m <- t(t(A) * B[colnames(B) %in% colnames(A)])
m <- cbind(m, rsums=rowSums(m))
> m
      ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4 rsums
row1 1.11 3.69 1.88 1.92  8.60
row2 2.22 1.23 2.82 0.96  7.23
row3 3.33 2.46 0.94 1.92  8.65
row4 2.22 1.23 1.88 2.88  8.21
```

PS: To avoid confusion, please post different questions in different posts, and not as edits of the original post.

Comment: or ```sweep(A, 2, B[colnames(B) %in% colnames(A)], `*`)```

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus `sweep()` is a very nice function. I should use it more often ;-)

Comment: Another option is `A*B[, colnames(A)][col(A)]`